# XSLT 1.0 - How to combine sub-string/concat/translate value of select

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to combine a sub-string, concat and translate so I can combine the string but capitalize the output but am having trouble.  I am using the below snippet of code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(translate(E_Firstname, ',', E_Lastname, ' ', E_MiddleInitial, '                       '), 1, 24), $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here?
I am getting an error that the wrong number of arguments were built into the translate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following XSLT expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(concat(E_Firstname, ',', E_Lastname, ' ', E_MiddleInitial, '                       '), $smallcase, $uppercase),1,24)"/>
```

It should fix your problem.

---

In a full example with the sample XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
    <E_Firstname>Homer</E_Firstname>
    <E_Lastname>Simpson</E_Lastname>
    <E_MiddleInitial>J.</E_MiddleInitial>
</Data>
```

and the sample XSLT-1.0 stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(concat(E_Firstname, ',', E_Lastname, ' ', E_MiddleInitial, '                       '), $smallcase, $uppercase),1,24)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
HOMER,SIMPSON J.
```